# ListView is not updating to show values of android:entries?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have just started to play with Android development and am trying to set up a basic ListView. The ListView will display a basic, static set of strings. However, in the graphical layout of activity_main.xml the proper strings are not displaying, instead it still says "Item 1, Item 2, etc."

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sportsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/sports_array" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="sports_title">Sports</string>

<string-array name="sports_array">
    <item>Basketball</item>
    <item>Soccer</item>
    <item>Football</item>
    <item>Baseball</item>
    <item>Tennis</item>
    <item>Badminton</item>
    <item>Rugby</item>
    <item>Handball</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

and the relevant piece of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Again I am very new to this so I wouldn't be surprised to see it is some rather simple error, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running this on an emulator or device; the preview may not honor the `android:entries` attribute.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Weird how it doesn't display on the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the listview in your activity like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.sportsList);
}
```